# Not able to wrap viewmodel in ko.validatedObservable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I would like to create viewmodel wrapped in ko.validatedObservable from the Json returned from server. I have read [Knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation#getting-started) documentation. Instead as documented there, I want to wrap the viewmodel using mapping so that isValid, and errors are part of the viewmodel rather than being part of an extra property.

I am using following javascript file (patientviemodel.js)  -

```
var patinetViewModelMapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        console.log("mapping");
        var patientVm = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, self);
        return ko.validatedObservable(patientVm);
    }
}
PatientViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    console.log("creating");
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, patinetViewModelMapping, self);

    self.Name = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: 'This field is required.' } });
    //self = ko.validatedObservable(self);
    self.save = function (action) {
        if (!self.isValid()) {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
            return;
        }
        var ajax = {
            url: "/patientregistration/" + action + "/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.patientViewModel != null) {
                    console.log(data.patientViewModel.Id);
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.patientViewModel, {}, self);
                }
                if (data.newLocation != null) {
                    console.log(data.newLocation);
                    window.location = data.newLocation;
                }
            }
        };
        $.ajax(ajax);
    }
}
```

I found that mapping is recognized if I change

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, patinetViewModelMapping, self);
```

to

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, patinetViewModelMapping);
```

However, though the viewmodel gets created as per the mapping, execution fails in save function with error that "isValid is not defined."

Call to applybinding happens in view(.cshtml) as below -

```
@model MSPro.Apps.ClinicManager.Web.UI.ViewModel.PatientViewModel
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register New Patient";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat });//new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}
Value of json : @data

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/lib/knockoutjs/dist/knockout.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/knockout.mapping/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/knockout-validation/dist/knockout.validation.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/setforgerytoken.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/patientviemodel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var patientViewModel = new PatientViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
        ko.applyBindings(patientViewModel);
    </script>
}
@Html.Partial("_EditPatientRegistration")

<p><button data-bind="click:function(){save('Create')}" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></p>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

bower.json contains (added for reference of version) -

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery-validation": "~1.15.1",
    "knockoutjs": "~3.4.1",
    "knockout.mapping": "~2.0.1",
    "knockout-validation": "~2.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.7",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "~3.2.6",
    "modernizr": "~3.3.1",
    "respond": "~1.4.2",
    "jquery": "2.2.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "knockout": ">=2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Very much new to Javascript. Your help will be very appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have referred to [Jef Cleas's article](http://www.jefclaes.be/2013/05/validating-composite-models-with.html?showComment=1480690565685#c235895650773812258).

The json referenced in the question looks like - 
     {
  "Id":0,
  "Name":null,
  "DateOfBirth":null,
  "LastActivityMessage":"Create a new patient record",
  "CreatedDate":null,
  "ModifiedDate":null,
  "CreatedBy":null,
  "ModifiedBy":null,
  "Row_Version":null
     }

Later it will contain child objects.

Comment: *"I want to wrap the viewmodel using mapping so that isValid, and errors are part of the viewmodel rather than being part of an extra property."* - Why?